# Row formula and capture that output value in declared(z) variable

Tags: excel, vba

Hi am using the below VBA but somehow I am not able to fix the issue.
Basically I try to capture Row formula of excel to count the number of row and return that value in a declared variable in VBA

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
z = WorksheetFunction.row(ClusterQuery)
End Sub
```

**ClusterQuery** is **NameRange** I am using.

Comment: `z = Range("ClusterQuery").Rows.Count`

Comment: Note that `.Rows.Count` returns a `Long` not an `Integer`. I recommend to use always `Long` instead of `Integer` as there is [no benefit in using `Integer` in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520).